# How to change Valuecolor of CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

How can i know the values to input in valueColor?

```
Container(
   height: 40,
   width: 40,
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: ???),
);
```

Comment: Check its [valueColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ProgressIndicator/valueColor.html) property

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>`.

```
Container(
   height: 40,
   width: 40,
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),
);
```